# Cannot get data from JTable because of NullPointer Execption

Tags: java, jtable

This code is an action listener for a button. I have a JTable that the user enters data into. It's filled with integers. For some reason, I'm able to println() every single one of the values. However, I'm not able to store them into my ArrayList because of a NullPointerException.

```
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        ArrayList<Integer> blades=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tableBlades.getModel();
        int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(nRow + ", " + nCol);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++) {
                blades.add(Integer.parseInt(dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString()));
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

(edit: added brackets for readability)

Based on the error log, I've been able to narrow it down to the line where I add the value to the ArrayList. I know that getValueAt() returns an object, so I used toString() and parseInt() to make it an integer. Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: you can check if dtm is null, or if dtm.getValueAt(i,j) returns null.

Comment: I'm sure that `getValueAt(i,j)` will be null

Comment: @PeterK `dtm` can't be null, or the `nRow` would throw a NPE - but otherwise, that is most likely.

Comment: Use Brackets (`{}`)! (Even when you don't need to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, you should learn how and step through the code to see what is happening.

`dtm.getValue(i,j)` is returning null for some combination of `i` and `j` when this is happening. With a debugger you can figure out exactly where it is happening.

If this is expected (that this can be `null`), then you should program defensively and enter a null check, something like:

```
Integer cellValue = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
if (cellValue != null) {
   blades.add(cellValue);
}
```

Of course, if it not OK for a cell value to be `null`, or to miss out on a value in `blades`, then you should handle that as an error, e.g. report back to the user that the data was missing, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into using the debugger and it turns out the last cell was left empty. The rest of the values were being saved just fine. I'll add the code to guard against nulls.